# Keycloak Userstorage SPI: how to use external application.properties?

Tags: keycloak

So I have a Userstorage SPI that connects to a DB. At the moment it is hard coded (db url, username, password, etc.) into the class and I would like to use an application.properties file near the jar.

So the keycloak folder structure should look something like:

```
keycloak:
  bin
  conf
  data
  lib
  providers
    my-userstorage-spi.jar
    application.properties
```

So when the keycloak starts: `bin/kc.bat start-dev`, the `my-userstorage-spi.jar` should read the values from the `application.properties`.

I am up for any solution. Autoconfiguration, file handling...

For example if I try to use it like this, it would say the file is not found:

```
Properties mainProperties = new Properties();
String path = "./application.properties";
FileInputStream  file = new FileInputStream(path);
mainProperties.load(file);

System.out.println(mainProperties.get("my.value"));
file.close();
```

The exception:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\application.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keycloak.conf file, for db url. For example:
add to keycloak.conf

```
spi-events-listener-id_spi-host=test.ru
```

and in your spi `config_scope.get("host");`

I be inspired [this code by example](https://github.com/svenstaro/keycloak-http-webhook-provider/tree/main/src/main/java/org/archlinux/keycloakhttpwebhookprovider/provider)